# Next step to take in direct proof or a workaround around current dilemma?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-writing, computer-science

This is a problem from Discrete Math and Its Applications
[image]

I used a direct proof to do this proof.
I understand the process/idea behind the direct proof, mainly 
(from https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse311/14au/slides/lecture07-filled.pdf)
[image]

Here is my work so far. 
[image]
Right now I am a mental roadblock. I did a substitution for n in the first equation and ended up with a proof that m - p is an even integer. Is there a workaround where I can get both positive m and p on one side(sum of the two) rather than the difference between the two?

Comment: Since $n$ is common in both $m+n$ and $n+p$ then $m$ and $p$ are either both odd or both even so that $m+p$ is even. This is because for $m+n$ to be even we may either have 2k+2k=4k=2(2k) or 2k+1+(2m+1)=2k+2m+2=2(k+m+1). Try adding an odd and an even and see what happens.

Comment: I get that idea but showing it via a direct proof

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** You showed that $m-p$ is an even integer. Now note that $m+p=(m-p)+2p$.

Comment: Thanks, and you go through an easier direct proof to show that the sum of two even numbers is even

Comment: Yes, so you know how to complete.  Alternately, we could have added $m+n$ and $n+p$, and subtracted $2n$.

Comment: thank you. Can you have a look at my latest question as well? This ones a bit tricky. I don't know how to proceed....

Comment: I see it has been answered. Let $n$ be odd. Then there is an integer $k$ such that $n=2k+1$. Now note that $2k+1=(k+1)^2-k^2$. We have explicitly exhibited two squares with difference $n$.

Comment: yeah thanks. the k + a and the k + b part was confusing to come up with.

Comment: You are welcome. The $k+a$, $k+b$ part is unnecessary, all we need is the identity $(k+1)^2-k^2=2k+1$. For some $2k++1$, there may be several squares whose difference is $2k+1$. For example $15=8^2-7^2=4^2-1^2$. But it is enough to show that there *is* a solution.

Comment: Andre, could you take a look at my latest question on proof by contradiction. Might need your expertise on what to do next :)

Comment: I looked, not good. We cannot prove it, it is false. Example, let $x=y=\sqrt{2}$.  Or else let $x$ be any irrational, and let $y=1/x$. Then $y$ is irrational, but $xy$ is rational. Many other examples. Ay one of them *disproves* the assertion.